# C++/CLI: FileSystemWatcher move or copy non empty folder

Tags: c++, events, c++-cli, filesystemwatcher

I'am working with the FileSystemWatcher in C++/CLI. I'am having trouble with moving or copying a non empty folder: When copy a folder with one .txt file in it to the watching folder, then multiple `created`and `changed` events are raised, that's fine, but when I move the same folder, only one single create event for the folder is raised. The problem is, that I need to know witch files are in it, so my idea was to just create a loop in the `changed` event that recursively searches trough the folder. This works for moving, but when I copy the folder, every event is raised twice.

I can't find an algorithm, so that only one `create` event for folders and files is raised.

Thanks for your help.

Code:

```
System::Void SnowDrive::Cloud::FileWatcher_Changed(System::Object^  sender, System::IO::FileSystemEventArgs^  e) 
{
    size_l  FileSize;

    string  ServerInode,
            FileName = c.marshal_as<std::string> (e -> Name),
            FilePath = c.marshal_as<std::string> (e -> FullPath),
            FtpPath  = ToFtpPath (FilePath.substr (0, FilePath.find_last_of ("\\")));

    if (FileName.find_last_of ("\\") != string::npos)
        FileName = FileName.substr (FileName.find_last_of ("\\") + 1);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < IgnoreFileList.size (); i++)
    {
        if (IgnoreFileList[i] == FilePath)
        {
            IgnoreFileList.erase (IgnoreFileList.begin () + i);

            return;
        }
    }

    if (!FileSystem::IsDir (FilePath))
    {
        FileSystem::FileSize (FilePath, &FileSize);

        if (FileSize != 0)
            IgnoreFileList.push_back (FilePath); // ignore twice changed events

        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        if (sender -> ToString () != " ")
            return;

        DIR * Dir;

        dirent * FindData;

        if((Dir = opendir(FilePath.c_str ())) == NULL)
            return;

        while ((FindData = readdir(Dir)) != NULL)
        {
            FileName = FindData -> d_name;

            if (FileName == string (".") || FileName == string (".."))
                continue;

            FileWatcher_Changed (gcnew String (" "), gcnew IO::FileSystemEventArgs (IO::WatcherChangeTypes::Created, gcnew String (FilePath.c_str ()), gcnew String (FileName.c_str ())));
        }
    }
}

System::Void SnowDrive::Cloud::FileWatcher_Created(System::Object^  sender, System::IO::FileSystemEventArgs^  e)
{
    size_l FileSize;

    string FilePath = c.marshal_as<std::string> (e -> FullPath);

    if (!FileSystem::IsDir (FilePath))
    {
        FileSystem::FileSize (FilePath, &FileSize);

        if (FileSize != 0)
            IgnoreFileList.push_back (FilePath); // ignore twice changed events
    }

    FileWatcher_Changed (gcnew String (" "), e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get only one `Changed` event like you want. I do, however, know how to get events for the moved files. You'll want to attach to the `Renamed` event.

Folder copy with files: One `Changed` event for the folder, and one per file.

Folder move with files: One `Changed` event for the folder, one `Renamed` event per file.

Comment: I tested what you said, but unfortunately no Renamed event is raised when I move the folder with a file

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you move the file itself, you get notified of the file move. If you move a directory with files, you don't get any notification for the files.